# Can a filter (in Spring Boot web app) validate a request URL, based on all defined RequestMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlet-filters

Is there any way to verify, within a servlet filter, if the request URL is valid (based on all the request mappings defined across all the controllers in the application?

I have implemented a filter in a Spring Boot web app (decorated with `@Component` and `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`. The filter is responsible for performing some validations on the received client certificate and if everything looks good, it passes the request further down the chain to be eventually picked up by a controller.

But I want to validate the URL before performing any other validations such as the cert validation, so I can indicate right away if it is a 404. Because I have run into a case where it has become necessary.

**Updated 9/23/2018**

`AuthFilter.java`

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthFilter.class);

    // Define paths that require only client certificate but no Authorization token
    private static final Set<String> ALLOWED_PATHS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
            new HashSet<>(
                    Arrays.asList("/login", "/register", "/error" )));

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.debug("Initiating AuthFilter...");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            return;
        }

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String path = httpRequest.getRequestURI().substring(httpRequest.getContextPath().length()).replaceAll("[/]+$", StringUtils.EMPTY);
        logger.debug("AuthFilter intercepting request: {}", path);
        boolean allowedPath = ALLOWED_PATHS.contains(path);

        int responseCode = 400;
        String responseException = null;

        if (allowedPath) {

            if (this.checkClientCert(CLIENT_CERT_NAME, httpRequest)) {
                logger.debug("{} cert is valid, moving request along", CLIENT_CERT_NAME);
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

            responseCode = 403;
            responseException = new AuthException("certificate missing", "Must provide a valid client certificate");
            sendResponse(responseCode, responseException, httpResponse);
            return;
        }

        try {

            logger.debug("Checking {} cert and authorization token...", CLIENT_CERT_NAME);
            boolean validClientCert = this.checkClientCert(CLIENT_CERT_NAME, httpRequest);
            boolean validAuthToken = this.checkAuthToken(httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization"));
            if (validClientCert && validAuthToken) {
                logger.debug("{} cert and Auth token are good!", CLIENT_CERT_NAME);
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseCode = 403;
            responseException = new AuthException("certificate or auth token is missing or invalid", "Must provide a valid client certificate and auth token");
            sendResponse(responseCode, responseException, httpResponse);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the filter that you've used, at least at the level of spring annotations + what does it implement?

Comment: @MarkBramnik I added the filter code. Essentially, I use a whitelisted set of request URL paths that require only a client certificate and the rest to require both client certificate as well as an authorization (bearer) token. In case a client meant to request one of the whitelisted paths (e.g. `/login`) but erroneously requested `/logi`, then the filter would end up performing checks for client cert and auth token. In order to avoid this, I'd like to validate the URL in the filter by leveraging a _Spring way_ of matching up the requested URL to any of the Request Mappings defined.

Comment: Please see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might misunderstand or misconstrued about java servlet filter and spring component.

But your problem can be solve by using 2 way:

- using servlet filter.
- using spring interceptor.

Comment: Possibly. I outlined the filter code to my original question. I have defined a whitelisted set of request URL paths that warrant checking for a client cert. Any other request URL paths warrant checking for both client cert and an auth (bearer) token. If a client typed an invalid request URL, the filter unnecessarily ends up performing the latter check. In order to avoid this, I was hoping to validate the URL using some Spring mechanism, to match with one of the Request Mappings, else indicate to the client that the URL is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC is built around one specific servlet with internal dispatching, based on spring controller configurations. Once the request reaches the centralized dispatcher, it checks mappings and routes the call to the specific controller. If there are no mappings, it throws an exception. Filter, that is a part of servlet specification, is too "low level", it can only catch a "general" request to spring MVC, so you won't be able to make it work with Filter abstraction because it has nothing to do with an internal routing of spring mvc endpoints.

However, you can use interceptors, spring specific way to intercept calls to certain controllers. The code of the interceptors will do the certificate based work.

In this case, the URL mapping will be checked automatically by Spring MVC framework.

If there are no spring controllers for the mapping, obviously their interceptors won't be called and 404 will be returned immediately.

You can find a tutorial about using these interceptors [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor)

But bottom line they act much like Filters with the main difference that they're "at the level" of spring MVC framework and not at the level of servlets (much lower).

Another possible solution (not directly related to your question though) is using Spring Security, from the question it looks like it could be a right abstraction for dealing with certificates, but it's only a side-note